# Is it possible to delete a record with Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I would like to delete all records related to a client. My datalake is composed of parquet files. Is it possible to delete data with a query on Athena

```
DELETE
FROM myTable
WHERE client_id=73513
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know there has been more than a year, but I decided to share it here because this comes out on top when you search for Athena delete. ACID level transactions are now supported for Athena using Iceberg
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-athena-acid-apache-iceberg/

Comment: Thank you, this is great news !

Comment: Well, now the Athena ACID transactions feature is available in GA.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible with Athena. `DELETE FROM` is [not supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unsupported-ddl.html) DDL statement.

Comment: Worth adding more context here. Athena is based on Presto .172 and .217 (depending which engine version you choose). The row-level DELETE is supported since Presto 345 (now called Trino 345), for ORC ACID tables only.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thanks. Wonder if AWS plans to add such support as well?

Comment: This I do not know.